# Find the concentration areas of one's in a unitary matrix

Tags: php, matrix

I've got some array of 0-1 elements like:

```
array('0,0'=>0,'1,0'=>0,'2,0'=>0,'3,0'=>1,'0,1'=>1,'1,1'=>1,'2,1'=>0,'3,1'=>0,'0,2'=>1,'1,2'=>1,'2,2'=>1,'3,2'=>1);
```

It looks like:

```
0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1
```

How to find all islands of 1?

In this case i would like to return values:

```
$island[] = array('3,0');
$island[] = array('0,1','1,1','0,2','1,2','2,2','3,2');
```

Of course in real cases are more expanded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be just me but I didn't understand the requirement

Comment: This matrix of yours, is it an array? Is it a single string with line breaks? What's the input type - that will make all the difference in the solution.

Comment: @asprin Based on the output, it seems to be coord references to the number 1 in the input. if the input is a 2D array, it is the numeric indexes that have the 1 in them.

Comment: Yes, in point of fact it is an array with x,y coordinates

Comment: I hope this is not some homework you are trying to get solved by us?

Comment: No no. Im 30 and in Poland we have holiday time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$islands = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
];

$result = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $islands,
    function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
        static $c = PHP_INT_MAX;
        static $r = -1;
        if ($c >= $key) {
            ++$r;
            $c = $key;
        }
        if ($value)
            $result[] = $key . ',' . $r;
    }
);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this exaple I get one array with 7 element. It should be two arrays with 6 and 1 element

Comment: Then explain the logic behind giving those two arrays: what's the difference between them? Why does one array have 6 entries, and the other only have 1? How do you make the decision of whether to put an island in one array or the other?

Comment: http://s15.postimg.org/xymc48lbb/tablica.jpg - islands are groups of 1 elements surrounded by 0 elements or edge of array - red island and green island

Comment: Meaning that for each island you need to do a lookahead/behind as well.... I'm assuming that's just within the row, and not by column as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach inside another foreach to trawl the arrays for values of 1 like this:

```
<?php 
    $array=array(
    array(0,0,0,1),
    array(1,1,0,0),
    array(1,1,1,1)
    );
    $island=array();
    foreach($array as $x=>$arr)
    {
        foreach($arr as $y=>$val)
        {
            if($val==1)
            {
                $island[]=array($x, $y);
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($island);
?>
```

with the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

This output finds all indexes of 1 and returns them as a a single entry in the array.

You can also use:

```
<?php 
    $array=array(
    array(0,0,0,1),
    array(1,1,0,0),
    array(1,1,1,1)
    );
    $island=array();
    $temp=array();
    foreach($array as $x=>$arr)
    {
        foreach($arr as $y=>$val)
        {
            if($val==1)
            {
                $temp[]="'".$x.','.$y."'";
            }
        }
        if(count($temp)>0)
        {
            $island[]=implode(',',$temp);
        }
        $temp=array();
    }

    print_r($island);
?>
```

Which will make an array closer to your required output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => '0,3'
    [1] => '1,0','1,1'
    [2] => '2,0','2,1','2,2','2,3'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, its not exactly what i mean :)